# parsing xml document using elementTree, python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("Parsed.xml")
doc = tree.getroot()

for elem in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/code'):
    print (elem.text);

for elem in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/codeSystem'):
    print (elem.text);
```

In above python code, I am getting values of code and codeSystem by specifying path, but they are printing like first all codes and then all codeSystem. I want to print them parallel (like column wise), so how can I edit the above code for parsing my xml doc.

see for example I have xml in this way, I want to print code and codeSystem in column wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the best way, but it should work. We scan the xml looking for `code` and `codeSystem`, trusting that they always appear in pairs (should be enforced by the xml schema).

We create two lists with the `code` vaules in one and `codeSystem` in the other, then output the lists by iterating through them to recreate the pairs.

```
codeList=[]
codeSystemList=[]

for elem1 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/code'):
    codeList.append(elem1.text)

for elem2 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/codeSystem'):
    codeSystemList.append(elem2.text)


for i in range(len(codeList)):
    print(codeList[i],codeSystemList[i])
```

*NB This answer was updated after new information was provided in the question so the first few comments should be ignored*

Comment: The above code i have tried already, what is happening is like if there are 17 codes and codeSystem are their under productCode, it is printing 17*17 rows.

Comment: Thought that might be a problem. Thanks for providing the xml sample. Do you just need the first pair of `code` and `codeSystem` for each of the `productCode` or do you need to include the later ones as well which have translated codes for different systems?

Comment: Updated the answer, please try the new code shown above

Comment: but as i am working with large data, is this possible to use two for loop like i and j, and append them? @CJC

Comment: Probably, but I haven't used ElementTree so I'm not certain how. As noted in my answer this probably isn't the best way to achieve the results you need, but a practical solution. You might need to target the `/productCode` level of the xml and then collect each value pair. Using a `find` command you might be able to scan through and find each pair in turn instead of using `findall`.